# Vaadin 23 UI navigate to target with route and query parameters

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

The following code I use to navigate to the target with Route parameters:

```
UI.getCurrent().navigate(ViewCandidateView.class, new RouteParameters(ViewCandidateView.PROFILE_UUID_PARAMETER, profileDecisionMatrix.getDecision().getUuid()));
```

which correctly leads me to the following url:

```
/candidates/a90bd8a9-0de8-4a10-ba82-e5a059eb861e
```

but I also need to add the query parameter - `job_id=100`, something like that:

```
/candidates/a90bd8a9-0de8-4a10-ba82-e5a059eb861e?job_id=100
```

what navigate method should I use in order to be able to provide Route and Query parameters at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use this

```
QueryParameters queryParameters = new QueryParameters(Map.of("job_id", List.of(100)));

navigateUI.getCurrent().navigate(
   ViewCandidateView.class, 
   profileDecisionMatrix.getDecision().getUuid(),
   queryParameters);
```